# Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE `branch` (
  `BranchID` INT NOT NULL, 
  `BranchSuburb` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `BranchState` char(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BranchID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `member` (
  `MemberID` INT NOT NULL, 
  `MemberStatus` char(9) DEFAULT 'REGULAR',
  `MemberName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `MemberAddress` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `MemberSuburb` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `MemberState` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `MemberExpDate` DATE,
  `MemberPhone` varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (`MemberID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `publisher` (
  `PublisherID` INT NOT NULL, 
  `PublisherName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PublisherAddress` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PublisherID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `BookID` INT NOT NULL,
  `BookTitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PublisherID` INT NOT NULL,
  `PublishedYear` INT4,
  `Price` Numeric(5,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BookID`),
  KEY `PublisherID` (`PublisherID`),
  CONSTRAINT `publisher_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PublisherID`) REFERENCES `publisher` (`PublisherID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `author` (
  `AuthorID` INT NOT NULL, 
  `AuthorName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `AuthorAddress` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AuthorID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `authoredby` (
  `BookID` INT NOT NULL,
  `AuthorID` INT NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`BookID`,`AuthorID`),
  KEY `bookID` (`BookID`),
  KEY `AuthorID` (`AuthorID`),
  CONSTRAINT `book_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`BookID`) REFERENCES `book` (`bookID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `author_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`AuthorID`) REFERENCES `author` (`AuthorID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `holding` (
  `BranchID` INT NOT NULL, 
  `BookID` INT NOT NULL,
  `InStock` INT DEFAULT 1,
  `OnLoan` INT DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BranchID`,`BookID`),
  KEY `bookID` (`BookID`),
  KEY `BranchID` (`BranchID`),
  CONSTRAINT `holding_cc_1` CHECK(`InStock`>=`OnLoan`),
  CONSTRAINT `book_fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`BookID`) REFERENCES `book` (`bookID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `branch_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`BranchID`) REFERENCES `branch` (`BranchID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `borrowedby` (
  `BookIssueID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BranchID` INT NOT NULL,
  `BookID` INT NOT NULL,
  `MemberID` INT NOT NULL,
  `DateBorrowed` DATE,
  `DateReturned` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReturnDueDate` DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BookIssueID`),
  KEY `bookID` (`BookID`),
  KEY `BranchID` (`BranchID`),
  KEY `MemberID` (`MemberID`),
  CONSTRAINT `borrowedby_cc_1` CHECK(`DateBorrowed`<`ReturnDueDate`),
  CONSTRAINT `holding_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`BookID`,`BranchID`) REFERENCES `holding` (`BookID`,`BranchID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `member_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MemberID`) REFERENCES `member` (`MemberID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Im getting the following error when i try to execute the last create query for the borrowedby table.
Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'holding_fk_1' in the referenced table 'holding'

Comment: Tidied your code for you please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for future reference

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is 'in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are the first columns in the same order' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: i ran your code in mysql 8.022 and it runs without a htch as you have already a primary key in holding for both columns, the error message doesn't fit with your code

Comment: Your code fails in Mysql 8.0.12 but runs fine in 8.0.22 As a workaround reverse the order of the columns: `CONSTRAINT holding_fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (BranchID,BookID) REFERENCES holding (BranchID,BookID) ON DELETE RESTRICT,`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to split the double foreign key? like this:

```
CONSTRAINT `holding_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`BookID`) REFERENCES `holding` (`BookID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
CONSTRAINT `holding_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`BranchID`) REFERENCES `holding` (`BranchID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

what dms are you using? could be that you need to use another syntax to reference two foreign key at one or could be that it's not supported.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.It worked when i reversed the order of the columns

Answer (score 0):

As said in the answer, just by changing order can fix it.

"Your code fails in Mysql 8.0.12 but runs fine in 8.0.22 As a workaround reverse the order of the columns: CONSTRAINT holding_fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (BranchID,BookID) REFERENCES holding (BranchID,BookID) ON DELETE RESTRICT, –
forpas
Oct 27 '20 at 15:50 "

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30435424)